# ¿Guargar grafico de funcion de MATLAB atraves de Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab

Hola hay alguna forma de guardar una grafica que esta en MATLAB ,guardarla en una ruta especifica atraves de Visual Studio ?

Trate de hacerlo si :

```
 PictureBox1.Load(Matlab.Execute("ezplot('x^2',[-2,2]) "))
```

Pero salta la ventana de MATLAB pero se muestra en el PICTUREBOX.

[image: Esta es la imagen que desearia guardar desde VB NET]

Me brindan ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas la función Execute con `Matlab.Execute` esto abre una instancia de Matlab y le pasa como parámetro la cadena de texto entre paréntesis, pero Matlab es quien decide como ejecutar el script y no tienes control de ese contexto desde tu aplicación, funciona como un hipervinculo web.

**Como alternativa:**
Podrías escribir una función mas compleja en matlab que guarde el resultado en un archivo y luego tratar de leer el archivo desde tu aplicación.